# Why did Bonnie's locator spell work?

Tags: the-vampire-diaries

Why did the locator spell work for Bonnie in season 2 when she used Jeremy's blood?

Bonnie said the spell requires the blood of someone biologically related.  However, in a previous episode Stevan confessed to Elana that she is adopted and is not a Gilbert. So how would the spell work if Jeremy and Elana are not in fact biologically related?

Comment: are you farther then season 2 the answer may be spoilers

Answer (score 2):

Elena and Jeremy are not brother and sister, true. However, they are cousins.

> Elena is the biological daughter of Isobel Flemming and John Gilbert. When Isobel was about to give birth, she went to Grayson's office for help (Grayson was John's brother). She fled after giving birth and Grayson and Miranda took Elena in. Two years later, Miranda gave birth to Jeremy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are cousins, since John Gilbert was Elena's biological father and Grayson Gilbert who is Jeremy's father, both John and Grayson were brothers. Elena was raised by Grayson and thought the entire time that she and Jeremy are siblings. But no they are cousins which is why Bonnie used Jeremy's blood to find Elena because they somewhat share the same DNA.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  While this is true, it has also been answered twice already.  Please don't post additional answers that just duplicate existing answers; you should only post a new answer if you have substantial new information.

Answer (score -1):

Yep, they're cousins. That confused me at first until I thought about it for a second. Their fathers were brothers.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything to the other answer.